# django admin url redirect to custom url

Tags: python, django, url

I am in a way of making a module for my project that can be reused later also.

Lets say I have an django app named "demo" and I have included it in root url like `url(r'demo/',include("demo.urls")),`

Now inside "demo.urls" I want to redirect admin url to custom url.

```
/admin/auth/group/add/
```

should be redirected to any url that is of demo.urls

Answer (score 1):

define a view function that redirects to your desired url:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def redirect_to_desired_url(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('new_url/')
```

and then in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 ...
  url(r'^/redirect_to_desired_url/$',redirect_to_desired_url),  
  ...
)
```